# Oracle-xe18-18c configure fails

Tags: centos, oraclexe

Following this [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/oracle-db-18c-xe-rpm-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-and-7), I'm trying to install Oracle-XE on CentOS.

However at the step `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure` I get stuck with this:

```
************
Prepare for db operation
7% complete
Copying database files
8% complete
[WARNING] ORA-00821: Specified value of sga_target 308M is too small, needs to be at least 440M
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

9% complete
[FATAL] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

29% complete
100% complete
[FATAL] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

7% complete
0% complete
Look at the log file "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/XE/XE7.log" for further details.

Database configuration failed. Check logs under '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.
```

Seems to be I need to change the sga_target param before database creation (before launching script). Problem is, I don't know how to do that. Any hint on how to get `configure` working?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Added more SWAP & RAM to my virtual machine and it worked (stuck for 0.5d for this...)